# Understanding Parquet File's metadata information printed with parquet-tools "meta" command

Tags: apache-spark, parquet, dremel

I am in the process of learning Parquet File's internal representation, so I went through Apache Parquet's Github [page](https://github.com/apache/parquet-format), Google Dremel's [paper](https://research.google.com/pubs/archive/36632.pdf) to understand the definition and repetition levels and Twitter's [blog](https://blog.twitter.com/engineering/en_us/a/2013/dremel-made-simple-with-parquet.html) to learn more about Parquet file.

To relate my understanding of its representation that I gained through my read with the actual Parquet files representation, I used `parquet-tools` command with `meta` option for one of the sample Parquet file and it printed details with 3 major sections, Header, File schema and Row_groups. I understood the details presented under the first 2 sections but I couldn't completely understand all the details present in the row group section.

Below are the questions that I have.

1. Wanted to know more about what `DO`, `FPO`, `VC` (This looks like the count of all the rows in the current row group) is. Expansion of what it stands for can be found in the parquet-tools Github [page](https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/tree/master/parquet-tools#row-group-column-details) but I wanted to get more details about it. I understand what `SZ` and `ST` is.
2. Next to `ENC` I see list of encoding schemes like `BIT_PACKED`, `PLAIN`,`RLE`. I understand what it means individually but I do not understand why there are at least 3 encoding schemes used all the times.
3. Next to Record count `RC` and total size `TS` of the row group, I see `OFFSET`. For the first page it is 4 always. How is it calculated?.
4. I came to know Parquet file's header and footer has 4 digit magic code as "PAR1", Does it have any special meaning? or just some arbitratry text to decide if the file is Parquet or not (without depending on the file extension).

Unfortunately I couldn't attach the snippet of the `parquet-tools meta` command's output due to security constraints but I hope it will not be too much to visualize what I mean in each of questions.

Answer (score 0):

This page has the best description i found:
https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/tree/master/parquet-tools-deprecated

So it seems tat DO, FPO are just offset infomation where the values of this particular columns starts. VC = Value count of existing non null values.

Parquet file creation with pandas

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'w1': ["John", "Max", "Hans"],
    'w2': ["Doe", "Mustermann", "Peter"],
    'w3': ["New York", "Berlin", "München"],
    'w4': [1990, 1980, 1970]})


df.to_parquet('./test_pandas.lz4.parquet', compression="lz4")
```

Meta output of parquet-tools.jar with `java -jar ./parquet-tools-1.10.1.jar meta <file>`

```
file schema: schema
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
w1:          OPTIONAL BINARY O:UTF8 R:0 D:1
w2:          OPTIONAL BINARY O:UTF8 R:0 D:1
w3:          OPTIONAL BINARY O:UTF8 R:0 D:1
w4:          OPTIONAL INT64 R:0 D:1

row group 1: RC:3 TS:440 OFFSET:4
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
w1:           BINARY LZ4 DO:4 FPO:51 SZ:98/79/0.81 VC:3 ENC:PLAIN_DICTIONARY,RLE,PLAIN ST:[min: Hans, max: Max, num_nulls: 0]
w2:           BINARY LZ4 DO:165 FPO:219 SZ:106/87/0.82 VC:3 ENC:PLAIN_DICTIONARY,RLE,PLAIN ST:[min: Doe, max: Peter, num_nulls: 0]
w3:           BINARY LZ4 DO:337 FPO:394 SZ:115/97/0.84 VC:3 ENC:PLAIN_DICTIONARY,RLE,PLAIN ST:[min: Berlin, max: New York, num_nulls: 0]
w4:           INT64 LZ4 DO:524 FPO:565 SZ:121/109/0.90 VC:3 ENC:PLAIN_DICTIONARY,RLE,PLAIN ST:[min: 1970, max: 1990, num_nulls: 0]
```